# Windows 7/8 IE Session data only accessible on the site

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cakephp, cookies

I have a CakePHP e-commerce website, this interacts with a third party site that allows the user to customise their product, before having the data sent back to our site to add this to their basket.

However when the third party site sends the product info to our site, the current session data does not seem to be accessible on IE under Windows 7 and 8 to our CakePHP code, the result is the product ends up getting assigned to a new basket instead of the customers current basket.

This all works fine on any other browser/operating system combination.

```
public function persistBasket() {
        $inSession = $this->Session->check('Basket.id');
        $inCookie = $this->Cookie->check('Basket');

        echo "insession ".$inSession;
        echo " cookie ".$inCookie;

        if ($inSession) {
            $basketId = $this->Session->read('Basket.id');
            if (!$inCookie || $basketId != $this->Cookie->read('Basket')) {
                $this->Cookie->write('Basket', $basketId);
            }
        } else if ($inCookie) {
            $basketId = $this->Cookie->read('Basket');
            $this->Session->write('Basket.id', $basketId);
        }
        echo " basketid ".$basketId;

        if (isset($basketId)) {
            // Set Basket model ID
            $this->Controller->Basket->id = $basketId;
        }
    }

    public function setupBasket() {
        $basketId = $this->Controller->Basket->setupBasket();

        if ($basketId !== false && $basketId !== true) {
            $this->Session->write('Basket.id', $basketId);
        }
    }
```

On Windows 7/8 when this code is run via the third party site it ends up with "insession  cookie " (and then an error because $basketid isnt set)

When the user is actually on the website we get "insession 1 cookie 1 basketid 100"

Comment: Haven't work with such engines, but it seems like a problem with accepting 3rd-party cookies.

Comment: @kirilloid your right, reducing IEs secrutity settings allowed it to work, now to figure out how to get it working with the standard settings